# Type 'null' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method

Tags: typescript

I have a function below that takes in numeric value and parses it into currency values like 11k, 1m etc... It achieves the task, but I am receiving ts error on this line:

```
const [match] = `${value / divider}`.match(regx);
```

**Error**

> Type 'null' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an
>   iterator.ts(2488)

**Full code**

```
export function getCurrencyValue(value: number) {
  const ranges = [{ divider: 1e6, suffix: 'm' }, { divider: 1e3, suffix: 'k' }];
  const regx = new RegExp('^-?\\d+(?:.\\d{0,1})?');
  let formatedValue = '';

  ranges.forEach(range => {
    const { divider, suffix } = range;

    if (value >= divider) {
      const [match] = `${value / divider}`.match(regx);

      if (match) {
        formatedValue = `${match}${suffix}`;
      }
    }
  });

  return formatedValue || value;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't destructure `null`, so

```
const [match] = `${value / divider}`.match(regx);
```

...would throw if there were no match, since `match` returns `null` when there's no match. You'll need to split that into two statements, or use the `|| []` trick or similar. Looking at your full code, it doesn't seem like destructuring helps here (because of the possible `null`), simply:

```
const match = `${value / divider}`.match(regx);

if (match) {
  formatedValue = `${match[0]}${suffix}`;
}
```

---

The reason the error message says what it says is that the kind of destructuring you're doing (using `[]`) relies on getting an iterator from the thing you're destructuring (the result of `match`). You get an iterator from something by using its `Symbol.iterator` method:

```
const it = `${value / divider}`.match(regx)[Symbol.iterator]();
```

Since one of the things `match` can return is `null`, and `null` doesn't (and can't) have a `Symbol.iterator` property, TypeScript complains about it.

---

Side note: `forEach` doesn't seem like the right tool here, since you want to stop the first time you get a match. Right now, you'll write to `formattedValue` for the `1e6` range, but then overwrite it with the result of formatting the `1e3` range.

`for-of` would be a good choice:

```
export function getCurrencyValue(value: number) {
  const ranges = [{ divider: 1e6, suffix: 'm' }, { divider: 1e3, suffix: 'k' }];
  const regx = new RegExp('^-?\\d+(?:.\\d{0,1})?');

  for (const { divider, suffix } of ranges) {
    if (value >= divider) {
      const match = `${value / divider}`.match(regx);
      if (match) {
        return `${match[0]}${suffix}`;
      }
    }
  });

  return String(value); // Presumably you always want it to be a string
}
```

I'd also probably use literal regular expression syntax for clarity (don't have to double-escape backslashes), and move both the `ranges` and `regx` outside the function so they aren't re-created every time (since this is in a module, and separately since the regex doesn't have the `g` or `y` flags):

```
const ranges = [{ divider: 1e6, suffix: 'm' }, { divider: 1e3, suffix: 'k' }];
const regx = /^-?\d+(?:.\d{0,1})?/;
export function getCurrencyValue(value: number) {

  for (const { divider, suffix } of ranges) {
    if (value >= divider) {
      const match = `${value / divider}`.match(regx);
      if (match) {
        return `${match[0]}${suffix}`;
      }
    }
  });

  return String(value); // Presumably you always want it to be a string
}
```

---

You've said you're not allowed to use `for-of` in your environment because you're transpiling to ES5 and not allowed to rely on regenerator-runtime. So instead of `forEach`, you'd want `some`:

```
const ranges = [{ divider: 1e6, suffix: 'm' }, { divider: 1e3, suffix: 'k' }];
const regx = /^-?\d+(?:.\d{0,1})?/;
export function getCurrencyValue(value: number) {
  let formattedValue = String(value); // Presumably you want it to always be a string

  // Not allowed to use for-of, and the rule saying not to use it also doesn't like `for` loops, so...
  ranges.some(({ divider, suffix }) => {
    if (value >= divider) {
      const match = `${value / divider}`.match(regx);
      if (match) {
        formattedValue = `${match[0]}${suffix}`;
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });

  return formattedValue;
}
```

Or with `reduce`:

```
const ranges = [{ divider: 1e6, suffix: 'm' }, { divider: 1e3, suffix: 'k' }];
const regx = /^-?\d+(?:.\d{0,1})?/;
export function getCurrencyValue(value: number) {

  // Not allowed to use for-of, and the rule saying not to use it also doesn't like `for` loops, so...
  return ranges.reduce((formattedValue, { divider, suffix }) => {
    if (value >= divider) {
      const match = `${value / divider}`.match(regx);
      if (match) {
        formattedValue = `${match[0]}${suffix}`;
      }
    }
    return formattedValue;
  }, String(value)); // Presumably you always want it to be a string
}
```

Comment: I agree for of loop approach looks much cleaner, however using it I get another unrelated ts error `iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations.`

Comment: @Ilja - That means you're transpiling to ES5 and "this guide" (whatever it is) doesn't want you to rely on the regenerator runtime. (The separate statement "loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations" seems like nonsense to me without further explanation from whoever wrote it. `for-of` uses array iteration.)

Comment: @Ilja - I've added solutions avoiding `for-of` by using `Array.prototype.some` or `Array.prototype.reduce`. If I weren't allowed to use `for-of` here I'd use `for`, but the second part of that error suggests it would complain about `for`, too, so... :-)